# React how to build the react page only after the script is finished running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a script that gets information from an API, but the problem im currently facing, is that the react page is being loaded before that script has finished loading, so pretty much im getting the page without the necessary information, and i need to reload the page to use the new information.
window.location.reload(false), is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Return `null` from the render method until the script is loaded.

Use state in the component to trigger the render again on script load.

For example:

```
const comp = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // API call
    setApiData(data)
  }, [])
  if (!apiData) {
    return null // or return a loader
  }

  // use apiData
  return (<div>{apiData}</div>)
}
```